# Remove some parts of URl with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm developing a website and trying to obtain:

```
http://localhost/dir1/dir2/index.html#home
```

to become:

```
http://localhost/index.html#home
```

Tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ /dir1/dir2/
```

but no luck, it redirects to `http://localhost/dir1/`!

My `index.html` file is under `/var/www/html/dir1/dir2` folder, as you imagine see from the URL.

Any help please?

Thanks

I'm developing a website and trying to obtain:

```
http://localhost/dir1/dir2/index.html#home
```

to become:

```
http://localhost/index.html#home
```

Tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ /dir1/dir2/
```

but no luck, it redirects to `http://localhost/dir1/`!

My `index.html` file is under `/var/www/html/dir1/dir2` folder, as you imagine see from the URL.

Any help please?

Thanks

*Edit**:

The `.htaccess` is placed in the root folder, so in `dir1`'s parent.

Answer (score 0):

to rewrite Rewrite 
http://localhost/dir1/dir2/index.html#home 
to 
http://localhost/index.html#home

use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   dir1/dir2/ ""
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work for me. Nothing changes in my URL. I tried both to directly call `http://localhost/dir1/dir2/index.html#home` and also adding a `/dir1/index.php` that executes `header('Location: ./dir2/index.html');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dir/dir/$ [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work for me. Nothing changes in my URL. I tried both to directly call `http://localhost/dir1/dir2/index.html#home` and also adding a `/dir1/index.php` that executes `header('Location: ./dir2/index.html');`